# How to rotate a curve in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I know how to rotate an object in Draw.io because usually there is an anchor where my mouse changes into the rotation mode. This is also explained in this tutorial:

https://support.draw.io/display/DO/Tutorial+3+-+Connectors%2C+Waypoints%2C+and+Altering+Shapes

However, a curve does not have this option:

[image: curve example]

Naturally, I could manually move every vertex, but I would prefer to have options to flip/rotate it as a whole.

I tried grabbing the curve with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, hoping that it would change from "move object mode" to "rotate object mode" but it does not work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- add one more object
- press down and hold **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**
- select your curved line and that object
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>G</kbd>**
- rotate it as you desire with that rotational arrow
- when done delete that extra object

  [image: 0]

Comment: Any way to delete the group after this step? When I try, the arrow rotates back to its original orientation.